# Comparing array values in Google Apps script

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I feel that the following two functions should produce the same result, but function `bob()` never finds `name1` equal to `name2`, even though the names in those cells are indeed equal.

The function `bob2()` works fine, but I'm trying to speed things up by using arrays.

```
function bob() 
{
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var name1 ;
  var name2 ;
  var AthName = ss.getRange(1,2,30).getValues();

  for (var xx=1; xx<30 ;xx++)
  {
    name1=AthName[xx]
    name2=AthName[xx+1]
  //name1 never equals name2 here. 
    if (name1==name2) ss.getRange(xx,10).setValue(name2);
  }
}


function bob2() 
{
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var name1 ;
  var name2 ;

  for (var xx=1; xx<30 ;xx++)
  {
    name1 = ss.getRange(xx,2).getValue();
    name2 = ss.getRange(xx+1,2).getValue();
  //name1 does equal name2 here as expected.
    if (name1==name2) ss.getRange(4+xx,10).setValue(name2);
  }
}
```

What's wrong with `bob()`?

Comment: try to add console.log('Name1:' + name1 + ', Name2:' + name2); in both functions and compare the values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with `bob()` is that you're setting `AthName` to a two-dimensional list of values:

```
var AthName = ss.getRange(1,2,30).getValues();
```

`Range.getValues()` always returns a two-dimensional list indexed by row and column.

This means that you're assigning lists to `name1` and `name2`:

```
name1=AthName[xx]
name2=AthName[xx+1]
```

Lists are equal only when they're the same list, *i.e.*, the variables refer to the same memory location. So `name1 == name2` is going to be false no matter what the lists contain.

The fix is probably evident to you by now. Retrieve the value from each row:

```
name1 = AthName[xx][0];
name2 = AthName[xx+1][0];
```

(I've added spaces and semicolons for the sake of good JavaScript style.)

Comment: Yes , working now. I was following code examples which did not specify a second [], Thank you so much, way to many expired languages in my head.

Comment: Just to show off how new I actually am, I'm only guessing that the green check mark means "accept"